# $a - $b = $a

Tags: php

Я делаю такую штуку :

```
$res = mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET life='life - 3' WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Это значит что должно от начального уровня жизней 12 отнять 3 , но оно вместо этого записывает в столбик life - 3 подскажите пожалуйста что делать =)

Comment: У Вас тип поля life неправильный. По смыслу надо числа, а не символы.

Comment: @Prikol дадите хоть поиграть помощникам бесплатно?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `life`=`life`-3 WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Comment: нужно указать что это полу и брать его в обратные кавычки. Иди вариант (`life` -= 3)